# Python cannot import .so using sys.path.append

Tags: python-2.7

I have project with structure like this

```
<Project_folder>
  |
  +-- somefile1.py
  +-- somefile2.py
        ...
  +-- cx_Oracle.so
```

In one of the files I'm trying to do

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "cx_Oracle"))
import cx_Oracle
```

but later in code

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(login, password, connection_string)
```

is trowing error

> 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

How can I properly import cx_Oracle.so ?

Comment: what is the output of `dir(cx_Oracle)`?

Comment: `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

Comment: what are the values of `cx_Oracle.__path__` and `cx_Oracle.__file__`?

Comment: `['C:\\OneDrive\\* censored *\\Packages\\2019\\PythonOracle\\cx_Oracle']`

Comment: is it where your `cx_Oracle.so` file located?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yes, it is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188477/discussion-between-azat-ibrakov-and-jmt).